# ef6 include() for nullable properties with required attribute

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

We've just updated to the EF6 and have an issue with a strange behavior comparing to the previous version.

EF used to generate LEFT JOINs for the Include statement if the property was nullable. However it looks like this version takes into account also the [required] attribute.

For example I have the following class:

```
public class Client
{    
    [DisplayName("Industry Code")]
    [Required]
    public int? IndustryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IndustryId")]
    public Industry IndustryEntity { get; set; }
}
```

When we do

```
return db.Clients
    .Include(o => o.CountryISOEntity)
        .... 
    .Include(o => o.IndustryEntity)
    .Single(o => o.Id == clientId);
```

the previous version generated LEFT OUTER JOIN, but the new one generates INNER JOIN.

If I remove the [required] attribute than it generates the LEFT JOIN. But it's not an option in my case as we use this attribute to show the errors to the user, however the user has an option to save the incomplete entity and to return to it later. And when the user comes back it get an error that the record doesn't exist as the include generates INNER JOIN.

Is there a setting in the new EF6 to disable this behavior (to ignore the attributes) and to generate sql query based on the nullable information? Or can I force the LEFT JOIN in the include? Or is our only option to rollback to the previous EF version?

PS: we are using .Net 4.0

Thanks

Comment: Don't lie to Entity Framework. If you're telling it that the property is required, Entity Framework will trust that it really is required. Why are you using the built-in `Required` attribute with its specific meaning that you don't like, instead of using a custom attribute?

Comment: Because it worked well before :) I thought that the Required attribute is used by MVC but not EF. It's mental if I have to change all Required attributes to custom attributes that do exactly the same as Required but not picked up by the EF. And in general I believe if the previous version behaved in one way it's not a very good idea to change this behavior as it brakes applications.

Comment: RequiredAttribute was also used by EF in EF5. But yes, I can agree that if it was used differently in EF5, then the change should at the very least be clearly communicated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to use the `Required` attribute for form validation in MVC, not to tell Entity Framework that the property is required. This is why you need view models, so you can separate validation logic of views from Entity Framework validation logic.

Your view models represents a view and contains all the data that is needed to render the view. A domain model (entity) represents one (or more) table(s) in the database. View models don't necessarily contain the same properties as the domain model. In my personal experience they are usually a combination of different domain models.

If you create a view model for a `Client`, you can remove the validation attributes from your EF POCO.

The view model will look like this:

```
public class ClientModel
{
    [DisplayName("Industry Code")]
    [Required]
    public int IndustryId { get; set; }

    // Other properties..
}
```

Then your POCO can look like this:

```
public class Client
{
    public int? IndustryId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("IndustryId")]
    public Industry IndustryEntity { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: That's a good option. And I believe it will work. However it's an old project and there are like 50 domain models there and God knows how many views (and they all use domain models). We will not have time to refactor the whole project (even thought we understand it's the right way). So it looks like we will have to rollback to the previous version of EF if we don't find the way to force it to ignore this attribute.

Comment: @Intetics I understand, it will be quite a refactor session to change it. But if you find the time or when you're going to rebuild stuff, you should definitely use them.

Comment: Agree. But meanwhile we're rolling back to EF5 (4.4) and I mark this answer as the correct one even though it doesn't fit to the dark reality of old projects.

Comment: @Intetics all right, thanks. Best of luck with your development!